# Wordpress post to user relation ship

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

Is there any way to connect post to specific user in wordpress. Is there any plugin available. Or any one know the code for doing that.I have a custom post type stories. When adding stories i need to chose the corresponding users from user list. Please help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Install Post2post https://wordpress.org/plugins/posts-to-posts/

Then in your function.php write this code

```
p2p_register_connection_type ( array(

'name' => 'releated_user',

'from' => 'story',

 'to' => 'user'
) );
```

here **story** is your custom post type slug. related_user is just a connection name.You can name it as what you like.

Then in your post type section you can see an option for selecting corresponding user.

Answer (score 1):

In the custom post type setup, you first need to ensure that this post type allows for authors to be set.

This comes in from the arguments when registering the post type.

```
$args = array('supports'=>array('author'=>true));
```

If you have an admin account, you can set who the author is using the quick edit function or by allowing to see it under screen options on the full edit page.

Other than that, you can make your own complete `post meta box` to allow for multiple authors. I cant see a plugin on the wordpress plugin directory so creating your own to fit your needs and wants will be your best bet.